# Login to another application after post request Spring JAVA

Tags: java

I write this controller and the main idia is that i want to login in another my web application using Post REQUEST. I tested it and the response is **200 OK !** but the controller only redirects me without log me in the another application. Please help.

```
@Controller
    public class BackdoorLoginController {

        private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

        @RequestMapping(value = "/loginTo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public void redirectWithUsingRedirectPrefix(HttpServletResponse res, HttpServletRequest request)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
            URL url = new URL(null, "http://www.url.com", new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());

            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            String urlParameters = "submit=1&email=email@email.com&pass=password";
            byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            int postDataLength = postData.length;

            // add reuqest header
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            con.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Host", "http://www.url.com");
            con.setUseCaches(false);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

            try (DataOutputStream q = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
                q.write(postData);
            }

            // Send post request
            // con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // print result
            System.out.println(response.toString());
            res.sendRedirect("http://www.url.com");
        }

    }
```

Comment: You probably did POST, and it did return 200, but how does that say you logged in successfully? You likely need  to store some "token" that indicates you're logged in

Comment: You want to login client to other web app through your backend? How was it supposed to work?

Comment: @cricket_007 how can i setup and use this token. Please give an example.

Comment: When you do that server itself is logging in, not the client. When you login you probably get a ticket, right? Then it's stored on cookie, so the only way is to give user this token, so user could use it, you might add it to it's browser cookies but cookie can't be shared through domains what means you wouldn't be able to set a cookie for url.com through foobar.com. You might get your token and return it to client and then try to reuse it to log in to the other app, maybe someone knows how to do that imho it's not possible

Comment: I don't have an example, but that is how OAuth2 works, I think. Like you can login via Google, Facebook, Twitter, Github, etc, etc. Each has their own API which returns an Oauth token, and that's what's stored, not your credentials in plaintext

Comment: @cricket_007 but you mean use another app to login to main app. In this case i understood he wants to login to the other app itself, not the main who is dealing with this request, is that still possible this way?

Comment: @Leonardo Lana i am trying to do login to main app using another app.

Comment: Why are you redirecting user to url.com? Anyway if you want to login to the main app then what you need to do is check if login was successful and then add principal to user's session

Comment: @Leonardo Lana OK! I will try.